# How to dump the crash message of a program into files?

Tags: python, linux, bash, crash

For example if I have a python file `test.py`.

Running `python test.py` in command line crashes with message:

```py
Segmentation Fault(core dumped)
```

How can I save such message into a txt file with a script? (Imagine I have test1.py, test2.py, test3.py... and they all crash. I want to collect the crash log of them all and do some analysis)

Comment: Are you talking about the message "Segmentation Fault(core dumped)" itself, or the core dump it produces?

Comment: Read first [core(5)](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man5/core.5.html) and [signal(7)](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man7/signal.7.html) and [syscalls(2)](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/syscalls.2.html) and the documentation of [GNU bash](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/) Consider using [gcore(1)](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/gcore.1.html) and [strace(1)](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/strace.1.html)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That message is coming from the shell, not the program. If you want to capture it, you need to run the command in a subshell so you can redirect the shell's output. You need to redirect stderr to get error messages.

```
for script in test*.py; do
    (python "$script")
done 2>errors.txt
```